# JSON Parsing with Android, problems with boolean

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to play around with Android development, but I can't seem to get passed this error when I try to parse some JSON coming from an API:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value true at 0 of type java.lang.Boolean cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

So, it can't handle "true"? That just seems silly. Here's the first part of the response, where it's failing:

```
[true,{"total":84,"results": ...
```

And here's how I'm trying to do the parsing:

```
new JSONArray(json);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Phil this is an example...

```
int mytotal;
if (result instanceof JSONArray) {
    JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) result;       
     JSONObject jo = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
      mytotal = jo.getInt("total");
    }
```

Comment: Arg, sorry about that. I thought there was a parsing error, turns out I was just being an idiot and making a mistake with the results. It all throws the same error, and I just wasn't paying attention. Thanks for your help!